# Xamarin - Turn on PC from Android phone by Wake on LAN (WOL)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wake-on-lan

I am a newbie in Xamarin. 
Now, I am developing an application to turn on PC from Android phone by Wake on LAN. My PC and phone are both in a LAN connection.
But when I execute code to turn on WOL, nothing is happen, my PC still not started.

Following is my code to do this:

```
client = new UdpClient ();
client.Connect (IPAddress.Broadcast, 9); //IPAddress.Broadcast return value is: 255.255.255.255
byte[] mac = new byte[] { 0x1C, 0x6F, 0x65, 0xC5, 0x9E, 0x68 };
byte[] packet = new byte[17 * 6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    packet [i] = 0xFF;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        packet [i * 6 + j] = mac [j];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine (packet);
client.Send (packet, packet.Length);
```

Thanks for all help :)

Comment: Have you enabled WOL on your PC? :D

Comment: Ok, let me quickly try your code...

Comment: Have you used Wireshark or something similar at the PC end to see if it is being received at that end?

Comment: @RafaelRegh: Thank you ^^

Comment: @JackHughes: No, I not use anything like Wireshark

Comment: If you're writing networking code, it is invaluable. Would help you know whether the problem is one of the packet not being received at the PC end or the packet itself being malformed.

Comment: @JackHughes: I had use Wireshark but found that UDP magic package not received at the PC end. Do you have any solution for this? Thank you ^^

Comment: Capture the packet being sent from your development machine. Examine the address it is being sent to in Wireshark. Is the address as you'd expect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85087/discussion-between-mr-neo-and-jack-hughes).

Comment: Did you find what was wrong with the code?

Comment: The code have no problem. I found that WOL is not allow to send from mobile to PC, @Bosiwow

Comment: What do you mean by that? The WOL package never exits the phone? Or does it never reach the computer?

Comment: Or was it because your mobile and computer were in a different subnet?